Set connection-level variables with PreparedStatement
In the following code, the commented-out line successfully sets myVariable, and the operations that follow this section execute as expected. However, when using the uncommented variation, conn.prepareStatement(sql) produces the error: "java.sql.SQLException: [SAP][JDBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Syntax error near 'host variable' on line 1"
try {
    // String sql = "create or replace variable myVariable integer = 123";
    String sql = "create or replace variable myVariable integer = ?";
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setInt(1, 123);
    // (...more code...)
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}

Following the execution flow in the debugger, the error occurs prior to ps.setInt(1, 123); (that line is never reached.)
It seems either I'm using the wrong syntax for this prepared statement or there may be some limitation with JDBC or SQLAnywhere. I've been searching the SAP docs but not yet found any information about this.

Did you check the syntax documentation of the statement? Does it actually allow/support a query parameter there? The error suggests it doesn't support that. A lot of SQL dialects only support parameters in DML, not in DDL like this.

Which driver is used for JDBC?

@MarkRotteveel I've not had much luck finding the syntax documentation for this. Are you able to point me in the right direction?

@RomanC Our pom.xml includes this line: <driverClass>sap.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IDriver</driverClass> , I've not yet been able to find the corresponding documentation for this. Are you able to point me in the right direction?

I don't use SQLAnywhere, but a quick search lead me to CREATE VARIABLE statement, which to me suggests it does not accept a parameter, but only literals or constant expressions.

when using PreparedStatement you can use the '?' in order to later in your code add a value to the '?', so for instance, if you want to check if integer = 123 you need to add the line: ps.setInt(1,123), that way you will be setting the 1st '?' to the integer value of 123, make sure to do it after declaring the ps.
if this still does not work you can always try doing this:
int x = 123; String sql = "create or replace variable myVariable integer = " + x; instead of using a '?'
and if that still does not work then the only thing that might be causing this error is a mismatch between variable types.

I've made an edit to my post for clarity. The ps.setInt(1,123); line is never reached - the error happens prior to that in conn.prepareStatement(sql);
